# Fantasy book with two parallel stories, one featuring the daughter of a slave who seeks a "dream stone"

Tags: story-identification, books, powers

The book is set with 2 different stories that carry on throughout.

A girl who lives in a wash house type place with her mother. Her mother is owned as a slave and is brandished with the scars of her master's "mark".  Daughter comes of age and is bought, I believe the man who buys her turns out to be her father but not too sure. Her mother tells her of a stone that is called something like a dream stone that she has hid next to a tree somewhere. This stone helps her control her power to walk through dreams and stops others from walking in her dreams.

The other story is set by a boy who meets the girl in his dreams.
They go on a journey to find each other/escape from the men chasing her.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall the cover art?

Comment: Was this set in our world? A fantasy one? Medieval? Contemporary? Pioneer? Part of me wants to suggest the Alvin Maker books, which have Peggy as the escaped slave and Alvin as the boy she contacts.

Comment: If it is Alvin Maker (although I can't find a reference to a "dream stone"), that would likely be *Alvin: Journeyman*, the third book.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/134903/story-identification-novel-about-a-girl-and-her-mother-who-survive-by-walking-t?rq=1 is also a partial match.

Comment: Sorry, *Prentice Alvin* is the third book. I typed the wrong name down.